# How to clear inputs after useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I am using useReducer to control my 2 inputs:

```
const [noteInput, setNoteInput] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    {
      title: '',
      content: ''
    }
  );
```

After onClick on button i want both inputs to be cleared. How can i do that after useReducer?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your state to empty using setState OR You can dispatch other actions for updating that state to the empty string.
 https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#reducers

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to use useReducer to clear your form you can use dispatch to do so.  Let's use this example button component as an example.

```
//Component
<Button onClick={() => {dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_FORM"})}}>Submit</Button>
```

After clicking the button "CLEAR_FORM" is dispatched to the reducer.

```
//Form Initial State & Reducer switch statement
export const initialState={
  username:"",
  password:""
}

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
   case: "CLEAR_FORM":
    return {
          username:"",
          password:"",
    }
   default:
    return state
    }
 }
```

When the reducer gets the { type: "LOG_OUT" }, in this case, it resets the username and password fields to an empty string.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a third argument to React.useReducer() called *init*. This is called lazy initialization and is a quick way to revert to the initial state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Button, you only need to alter onSubmit={handleSubmit} and have the function below and things will be all good. Just remember not to set defaultValue of any TextField or what you are using, just set the value only

```
const handleReset = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Object.keys(formInput).forEach((inputKey) => {
        setFormInput({ [inputKey]: '' });
    });
};
```